# Invalid syntax while installing bcrypt with npm on w10 x64

Tags: node.js, windows-10, bcrypt

I have python 2.7.15 and 3.7 installed on my machine.

I ran this command per
https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#microsoft-windows

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

When I run `npm install --save bcrypt`, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys> npm install --save bcrypt

> bcrypt@3.0.7 install C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.7 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Yael-PC1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Yael-PC1\\Projectz\\ys\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node"
"--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Yael-PC1\\Projectz\\ys\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Yael-PC1\\Projectz\\ys\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yael-PC1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-14T02_49_00_828Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys> ^C
PS C:\Users\Yael-PC1\Projectz\ys>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this.

If you look at the lines at the end, it says NOT OK, when it looks at your node version and the node-pre-gyp version

The easiest solution to this should be to just upadate npm, node and node-pre-gyp

```
npm install npm@latest --save
npm install node@latest --save
npm install node-pre-gyp@latest --save
npm install prebuild@latest --save
npm install node-gyp@latest --save
npm install bcrypt --save
```

This should theoretically take care of the error you're getting.

HOWEVER

If this still persists, you can consider switching to bcryptjs, which will work with your code if you're just using the hash and compare functions, and also has no dependencies, so it is a safer bet.

Comment: Ran those commands but got that same response. But bcryptjs installed just fine. Testing it out now.

Comment: Did you change all your dependencies? I should also warn you that bcryptjs is noticeably slower.

Comment: Yes I did. I got it working. Thank you. I will also keep that in mind. This is for a side project, so I don't expect much traffic, probably < 20 users a month.